# why less.js can't compute the color variables, but it computed when compile the less file to css?

Tags: css, less

i use variables in less file like this:

```
@base-color: #8156A3;
@base-color-darker: (@base-color - #111);

#searchForm{
   border: 1px solid @base-color-darker;
}
```

when i compile the less file to a css file, variables work correctly, but when i use the less file as page style sheet, the variables does not affect in elements.

this is how i link the less.js and the less style sheet:

```
<script src="assets/js/less.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/less/main.less" />
```

what's could be the wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Client-side usage](http://lesscss.org/#usage):

> Link your .less stylesheets with the rel set to “stylesheet/less”:
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
> ```

But your code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/less/main.less" />
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And:

> Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.

... but you have it the other way round:

```
<script src="assets/js/less.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/less/main.less" />
```

To sum up: don't guess :)

Comment: oh i included styleshhet before the script.
well, i correct the wrongs you mentioned, but now the page load without any styles. is this about all ppl using less, or another wrong still in my code?

Comment: solved, my ajax script made some errors in local and has conflict with other scripts. its work correctly in server. 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

For less.js to correctly parse the stylesheet you need to set the `rel` attribute to `stylesheet/less` when including the less file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="assets/less/main.less" />
```

You also need to include your stylesheet *before* less.js.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't know about .less extensions. You need to give them only the compiled css.

LESS and SASS were made to help you code faster, not as a replacement of CSS.

Comment: No idea about SASS but LESS ships with an optional client-side compiler, which is the tool the OP is trying to use.

Comment: its take a little more time for compiling. :d
i thing the only way to solve my issue is to use the compiled css.
thank you